# AWS Beanstalk EC2 instance immediately terminates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I'm deploying a simple nodejs app with Elastic Beanstalk. From what I can tell, I have configured the correct "Service Access".

I'm using...

**aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role**

- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
- AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser <-added thinking this might fix it

**aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role**

- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser <-added thinking this might fix it

My EC2 instances immediately terminate with the message

> "StateReason": {
> "Code": "Client.InvalidKMSKey.InvalidState",
> "Message": "Client.InvalidKMSKey.InvalidState: The KMS key provided is in an incorrect state"
> }

Any idea what might be causing this? I can launch EC2 instances manually with no problems.

Comment: Looks like you are using KMS key for encryption, can you check that key and provide us more info how are you using it?